# script tag with Dynamic variables in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'd like to add `Google Analytics` and `Google Tag Manager` on my web.

I'm trying to separate it as stages. (dev, prod)

**_document.tsx**

```
import Document, {Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
export default class MyDocument extends Document{
  render(){
    return (
      <html>
        <Head>
          {/* ... */}
          <script async src="http://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXX-X"></script>
          {/* ... */}
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </html>
    );
  }
}
```

What I expect

```
<script async src=`http://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${process.env.GTM_CONTAINER_ID}`></script>
```

I wanna use like above that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like normal JSX, you use curly braces to embed a JavaScript expression in an attribute.

```
<script async src={`http://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${process.env.GTM_CONTAINER_ID}`}/>
```

Comment: I've just forgotten it temporally. Thank you :)

Comment: No worries. I had the same question before.